# ArrayReferenceField(ManyToManyField) in django-admin, Djongo/MongoDB

Tags: django, mongodb, djongo

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjOVd.png)I catch error while saving `Diary` document in django-admin

[image]

Here `Diary` model

[image]

#### Edit:

I would like the same functionality as the group model, because they too refer to a collection of permissions

[[image]]

Answer (score 0):

First Please Add Records Model then change

```
records=models.ManyToManyField('Records',related_name='records')
```

Comment: theese `records` in diary admin, already exists,

Comment: I would like the same functionality as the `group` model

Comment: Can you Please Share Codes and Output or Error logs